# Why the variance of a proportion using multiple survey questions is the same as the proportion of only one survey question?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution, survey, bernoulli-distribution

I am measuring the proportion of a sample that gets all successes in 10 different questions of a survey. For example, one question is "Do you smoke?" and a success for me is "No". Another question question might be "How old are you?" and the success is for me is to be older than 15. I want to know what percentage of the population gets all successes in 10 different questions, and what is the margin of error of measuring that.

When I had to calculate the variance of this proportion my first instinct was just to calculate it as $\frac{p(1-p)}{sample\_size}$, where p is the probability of getting all successes. But then I thought that this should have more variance than answering one question that has probability p of being a success, so I coded a simulation. After coding it I found that they have the same variance (as long as the have the same overall probability), can somebody help grasping why is this?

Comment: The questions are quite different, but it seems they all have the same probability of "Success." How do you determine $p?$

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between two situations.

1 - The chances of success in all 10

2 - The average chances of success on a question, averaged over ten question.

You are calculating the former both by hand and in your simulation but your intuition is about the second one.

Comment: Let's say the chances of 1 is p. Why that has the same variance as a Bernoulli probability p?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i,\ i = 1, 2, \dots 10$ be the success probabilities for the ten questions.
If the questions are independent, then the probability of ten successes is
$P_{10} = \prod_{i=1}^{10} p_i.$

In case it helps you visualize my interpretation of your process, here is a simple simulation in R.

```
set.seed(724)
p = seq(.7, .9, len=10);  p  # vector of ten probabilities
[1] 0.7000000 0.7222222 0.7444444 0.7666667 0.7888889
[6] 0.8111111 0.8333333 0.8555556 0.8777778 0.9000000

x = replicate( 10^6, sum(rbinom(10,1,p)) )
mean(x == 10);  prod(p)
[1] 0.104008         # aprx result from simulation
[1] 0.1039915        # exact result
2*sd(x == 10)/sqrt(10^6)
[1] 0.0006105421     # 95% margin of SIMULATION error
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'a margin of error' for the number $P_{10}.$ 
For a simpler example, suppose a coin has success probability $p = .9,$ what
is the probability of getting ten Heads in ten independent tosses? Answer: $(.9)^{10} =  0.3486784.$ It would be analogous to ask, "What is the margin of error for measuring that?"

[By the Central Limit Theorem, a 95% margin of *simulation error* in
the simulation above is about $\pm 0.0006,$ which indicates that a million
iterations is enough to get 2 or 3 place accuracy for $P(X = 10).$ The R
code above gives about the same result as $1.96\sqrt{.104(1-.104)/10^6}.]$

*Note:* In your case, I wonder whether questions are independent. I hope
that the proportion of smokers among children $\le 15$ years of age is less than the proportion
in the general population.